# I recently upgraded Xcode 8.3.1 and Mac to Sierra. When I try to run my app on my iPhone 6s I get the following error. How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling all pods but have no idea how to fix this. My app gets to the loading screen then crashes.

> dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPVs11AnyHashables20_AnyHashableProtocols
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/476E6613-F069-42F5-B10D-5F56C0A357C3/Myapp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>   Expected in:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/476E6613-F069-42F5-B10D-5F56C0A357C3/Myapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>   in
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/476E6613-F069-42F5-B10D-5F56C0A357C3/Myapp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>   (lldb)

Comment: I also upgraded Alamofire to 4.4. It obviously has something to do with alamofire but I'm clueless on how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: BTW, have you deleted the previous version from your iPhone?

Comment: Yes I deleted it.

Comment: Try "Embed Binary" instead of linking framework: "General -> Embedded Binary -> Plus-Sign -> Choose Alamofire.framework"

Comment: Worked! Thank you.